# Reordering pairs in perl array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a series of 2-D coordinates being supplied to a perl program from another program. There are 4 of these and they make up a quad, giving 8 numbers in total, e.g:

`x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4`

I want to ensure that they are all specified in the same order, i.e. clockwise or counter clockwise. I already know how to do this and am doing it by looking at the sign of a cross product.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "-0.702083 0.31 -0.676042 -0.323333 0.74375 -0.21 0.695833 0.485";
my @coord = split(/[,\s]+/, $line);

# Vector cross product (Z is 0) to test CW/CCW
my @v1 = (-$coord[2]+$coord[0], -$coord[3]+$coord[1]);
my @v2 = (-$coord[2]+$coord[4], -$coord[3]+$coord[5]);
my $cross = ($v1[0]*$v2[1]) - ($v1[1]*$v2[0]);
```

Once I've worked out if the order needs to be changed I currently change it using:

```
@coord = ($coord[6], $coord[7], $coord[4], $coord[5], 
          $coord[2], $coord[3], $coord[0], $coord[1]) if ($cross < 0);
```

This works, but I'm fairly sure it's not the nicest way of writing it in perl. Is there a more elegant, "perly" way of writing this change in order? Something that would work for `$n` 2-D pairs preferably. It's not a simple reverse the elements of an array problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last couple of lines can be rewritten using an array slice:

```
@coord = @coord[6,7,4,5,2,3,0,1] if $cross < 0;
```

To process an arbitrary number of pairs, you can use `List::MoreUtils::natatime`

```
use List::MoreUtils 'natatime';   

my $it = natatime 2, @coord;
@coord = (); 

while (my @vals = $it->()) {
    unshift @coord, @vals;
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks for the missing syntax. Can the indicies for the slice be a list, or better yet some expression that generates that sequence?

Comment: @awoodland: of course. For example, you can say `@arr[0 .. 3]`. This works even when a slice is interpolated in the double quotes

Answer (score 2):

For `$n` 2-D pairs, you'll need a function that returns a list of the new ordering.
For example for `$n == 8`:

```
sub reorder {
    my $n = shift;
    return (6,7,4,5,2,3,0,1) if $n == 8;
}
```

Then you can use that in the array-slice:

```
$n = 8;
@coord = @coord[reorder($n)] if $cross < 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem, and settled on this concise algorithm:

```
splice @coords, $_, 2, [ $coords[$_],$coords[$_+1] ]  for 0..$#coords/2;
@coords = map { @$_ } reverse @coords;
```

The first line converts a flat list into a list of coordinate pairs, for example,
`(0,1,10,11,50,51) ==> ( [0,1], [10,11], [50,51] )`.

The second line reverses the order of the pairs and flattens the list again.

---

**Update**: Even more concise:

```
@coords = @coords[reverse map{$_ ^ 1}0..$#coords] if $cross < 0;

@coords = @coords[map {-$_ ^ 1} 1..@coords] if $cross < 0;

@coords = @coords[map {$_ ^ -1} 1..@coords] if $cross < 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on eugene's answer. A way to build the reversed list:

```
my $i = 0; 
unshift @i, $i++, $i++ while ($i <= $#coord); 
@coord = @coord[@i];
```

Comment: From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html): modifying a variable twice in the same statement will lead to undefined behavior

Comment: That's a ridiculous thing for perlop to say; in general it takes some work to understand execution order in more complicated cases, and there are corner cases where it gets even harder, but it is well defined (at least by the perl source :) ) and not subject to change.  I think that comment was added just to have something to respond to people who set out to confuse themselves.

Comment: @ysth, while mostly true, there are a few cases that are dependent on the C compiler used. And the C standard also states these same cases are undefined behaviors.

Comment: um, no, that is completely false, Ven'Tatsu